# Local Extrema (Weird Cases)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let me start out with my definitions:

Given a function $f$, a point $(x_0,f(x_0))$ is a *local maximum* if there is an open interval containing $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)\geq f(x)$ for all x in the interval. (There is a corresponding definition for *local minimum*.)

There are a few examples I have in mind that I would like to talk through and figure out if my reasoning is correct.  (I'm basically asking "Is there a local extremum at $x=0$?")

1. $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x+1 & x\leq 0\\-x &x>0\end{array}\right.$
2. $g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}-x+1 & x\leq 0\\-x &x>0\end{array}\right.$
3. $h(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}-1/x^2 & x\neq 0\\1 &x=0\end{array}\right.$
4. $j(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 & x= 0\\0 &x\neq0\end{array}\right.$
5. $k=\{(0,1)\}$

First off, the first derivative test fails for the first four of these functions at $x=0$ because they are not continuous there.  This leads us to have to go back to the definitions.

Reasoning:

1. The point $(0,1)$ is a local max since I can find an open interval (say, $(-1/2,1/2)$) such that $1$ is the largest attained $y$-value.
2. The point $(0,1)$ is neither a local max nor a local min because every open interval around $0$ necessarily contains values both greater and less than $1$.
3. The point $(0,1)$ is a local max using the same reasoning as in 1.
4. Same as 1. and 3.
5. By the definition, I need an open interval about the point.  There are no such intervals.  It seems then that it is neither a local max nor a local min.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $k(x)=\{(0,1)\}$. What is e.g. $k(0)$? What about $k(\frac12)$?

Comment: A function is a subset of the Cartesian product of two sets.  Perhaps I should rewrite as $k=$ rather than $k(x)=$ to be proper.

Comment: So you mean $k:\{0\}\to\mathbb R$ with  $k(0)=1$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean:  Dom$(k)=\{0\}$, CoDom$(k)=\mathbb{R}$, and im$(k)=\{1\}.$  Although, now that I am pondering it, I don't see how changing the codomain to $\{1\}$ would change the extrema.